# String reasonString = reason(i); gives compilation error;reason is in red colour

Tags: android

reason is in red colour(compilation error)

```
@Override
    public void onFailure(int i) {
        //String reasonString = reason(i);//---> reason is in red colour(compilation error)
}
```

Comment: where exactly is `reason()` defined

Comment: What `reason()` function does here?

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?

Comment: compare integer with integer not with String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scope of the reason() method must be,

1. inside that class in which, onFailure() method is overriding.
2. if you are using reason() method inside anonymous class ,then define reason() outside of that anonymous class.
3. if that anonymous class is user define, then define reason() method in that anonymous class.

Comment: I saw in some codes and  thought reason is a system routine.

Comment: yeah, it's not System routine.It's user define method, so you also have to define it